# Call a method in the nest.js project with Camunda (looking for an approach)

Tags: node.js, nestjs, microservices, camunda

Let's assume the following situation:

1. We have several webservices based on Nest.js technology
2. The services perform CRUD operations in the area of ​​their domain
3. The services do not have business logic (they can add, change, delete, return data, they know the relationships between entities, but also between domains (e.g. through Apollo Federation)

Everything works fine so far.

However, we face the problem of business processes, validation, business rules and everything that goes with it. So we have to code this logic somehow or use some engine (eg Camunda).

As far as I understand that Camunda can send requests from Service A to Service B in the BPMN process e.g. via HTTP.
But what if several activities are performed in the same service?
Isn't it better to make requests to the same service at the service level layer? Is it possible in Cmunda?

E.g.

WebService1 has a POST Customer/ endpoint which calls CustomerService.AddCustomer (data) and CustomerRoles.AddRole (data). Can we call CustomerRoles.AddRole in Camunda?

My question is mainly about node.js / nestjs.

Forgive me, but I don't think I can describe it more clearly :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you can use Camunda not only at the highest orchestration layer, for the end-to-end business process, but also inside the micro service. Benefits include state management, error handling, retries, exception handling, possible compensation. (What happens if AddCustomer succeeds, but AddRole fails?).
There are orchestration vs choreography considerations. Latency requiremnts may also be relevant. I recommend these two reads, which illustrate the benefits/trade-offs and design decision well:
https://blog.bernd-ruecker.com/the-microservice-workflow-automation-cheat-sheet-fc0a80dc25aa
and
https://blog.bernd-ruecker.com/3-common-pitfalls-in-microservice-integration-and-how-to-avoid-them-3f27a442cd07
Why don't you implement a little proof of concept and see what it could look like? If NextJS is your world, you may like to start with a Camunda 8 SaaS trila and https://github.com/camunda-community-hub/nestjs-zeebe#readme

Comment: Referring to the first of your links, but also to the statement on the Camunda website that Camunda is language independent. Is there any library for Node.js / Nest.js that would allow the Camunda / Zeebe engine to be used directly in JavaScript code? This first link shows the option "Decentralized engines, meaning you run one engine per microservice" - but can this be done in Node / Nest? Node.js Client probably allows you to connect to Camunda, and not do the flow directly in the Node.js service? BTW: Thank you for your greate answer!

Comment: I don't understand something else here and maybe someone will explain it to me. If the request comes to the controller, and the controller invokes an action in the service layer, and the service in the data access layer. Where in this sequence should the flow engine be to change the standard flow: Controller-> Service-> Repository. If I dynamically want to validate the request using Camunda, then probably Camunda / Zeebe should be called between Controller and Service? So: Controller-> Camunda-> ServiceLater OR Failure response from the Controller? Do I get it wrong?

Comment: With Camunda 8, and in general for JS, there is no embedded engine approach. The engine always runs in a container, either Saas or self-managed. There is no language dependency because the communication with the engine uses the client library in the language of your choice. So you would use https://docs.camunda.io/docs/apis-clients/community-clients/javascript/
Where this makes sense, the controller would communicate the request to the engine, which would orchestrate the invocation of the necessary services to create the result. If the overhead introduced makes sense depends on the use case.

Comment: Done. Did you read my comments and can give me an advice please?

Comment: My reply is in the other comment. Saw it?

Comment: I have aked additional questions in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74145357/when-the-bpmn-process-shoud-start-in-the-microservices-architecture-with-camunda