# When the BPMN process shoud start in the microservices architecture with Camunda orchestration

Tags: microservices, camunda, bpmn, orchestration

Consider an architecture like this:

1. API Gateway - responsible for aggregating services
2. Users microservice - CRUD operations on the user (users, addresses, consents, etc)
3. Notification microservice- sending email and SMS notifications
4. Security microservice - a service responsible for granting / revoking permissions to users and clients. For example, by connecting to Keycloak, it creates a user account with basic permission
5. Client - any application that connects to API Gateway in order to perform a given operation, e.g. user registration

Now, we would like to use Camunda for the entire process.
For example:
Client-> ApiGateway-> UsersMicroservice.Register-> SecurityMicroservice.AddDefaultPermition-> NotificationMicroservice.SendEmail

We would like to make this simplified flow with the use of e.g. Camunda.

1. Should the process start in UsersMicroservice.RegisterUser after receiving "POST api/users/" - that is UsersMicroservice.RegisterUser starts the process in Camunda and how does this endpoint know what specific process is to run in Camunda?
2. What if the BPMN process in Camunda is designed in such a way that immediately after entering the process there will be a Business Rule Task that will validate the Input and if there is no "Name", for example, it will interrupt the registration process? How UsersMicroservice will find out that the process has been interrupted and it should not perform any further standard operation like return this.usersService.Create (userInput);
3. Should the call to Camunda be in the Controller or rather in the Service layer?
4. How in the architecture as above, make a change to use Camunda to change the default Client-> UsersMicroservice-> UsersService-> Database flow, adding e.g. input validation before calling return this.usersService.Create (someInput);

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to let the process engine orchestrate the business process, then why not start the business process first? Either expose the start process API or a facade, which gets called by the API gateway when the desired business request should be served. Now let the process model decide which steps need to be taken to serve the request and deliver the desired result/business value. The process may start with a service task to create a user. However, like you wrote, the process may evolve and perform additional checks before the user is created. Maybe a DMN validates data. Maybe it is followed by a gateway which lead to a rejection path, a path that call an additional blacklist service, a path with a manual review, and the "happy path' with automated creation of the user. Whatever needs to happen, this is business logic, which you can make flexible by giving control to the process engine first.

1. The process should be started by the controller via a start process endppoint, before/not form UsersMicroservice.RegisterUser. You use a fixed process definition key to start. From here everything can be changed in the process model. You could potentially have an initial routing process ("serviceRequest") first which determines based on a process data ("request type") what kind of request it is ("createUser", "disableUser",...) and dispatches to the correct specific process for the given request ("createUser" -> "userCreationProcess").
2. The UsersMicroservice should be stateless (request state is managed in the process engine) and should not need to know. If the process is started first, the request may never reach UsersMicroservice. *this.usersService.Create* will only be called if the business logic in the process has determined that it is required - same for any subsequent service calls. If a subsequent step fails error handling can include retries, handling of a business error (e.g. "email address already exists") via an exceptional error path in the model (BPMNError), or eventually triggering a 'rollback' of operations already performed (compensation).
3. Controller - see above. The process will call the service if needed.
4. Call the process first, then let it decide what needs to happen.

Comment: If I understand correctly: endpoints should not call anything in the service layer at all in my scenario? Should they only specify action, input, autput, and the service layer call should belong to Comunda? So there should be a process key in header that endpoint uses to send to Camund, and it does the rest?

Comment: "Either expose the start process API or a facade, which gets called by the API gateway when the desired business request should be served" - I'm not sure can I run the process before the endpoint since I'm usning GQL Federation, which aggreates all the services in a single point. I don't think I have any influence on what happens in the services invocation process there in the API Gateway. So I don't know how to put some kind of facade in there. Theoretically, your concept makes sense, but I don't know how to implement it. https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/federation